# Creating a .so library that depends on message headers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to create a library that depends on header files generated by a call to `generate_messages()`. The message list is:

`project(ros_otp22)`

`add_message_files( FILES hydraulic_arm.msg valve_command.msg valve_command_info.msg angular_rate_info.msg slope_info.msg accel_info.msg )`

The library call is `add_library(o22pac src/o22pac/o22pac.cpp)`. This sometimes works and sometimes doesn't depending on the exact order in which the message header files are generated.

What I need is a list variable that does into the `add_library()` call that lists the *files*. Using `${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_message_cpp` (such as for `add_dependencies()`) does NOT work as it does not generate a list of header file names.

I could create my own list of headers, but that seems like a monumental waste of time an effort, source of bugs and misconfiguration and violation of the 'DRY' (don't repeat yourself) principle since `catkin_make` and `cmake` should already be aware of what headers the `.msg` files generate.

Is there a variable generated by `catkin` that represents a list of the header files by name? My searches of the documentation have found nothing promising.

Thanks,
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175180/creating-a-.so-library-that-depends-on-message-headers/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-06-27**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/?answer=54418#post-id-54418

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-06-29**:
I did see this answer, but it is talking about adding executables, not adding libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is that you have to add the `add_dependencies()` call *after* the `add_library()` call.

Unfortunately a lot of frustration was caused by the fact that neither the documentation at:
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt or
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html states this explicitly.

---

Originally posted by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) with karma: 163 on 2014-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-30**:
I may be biased here, but doesn't that just 'make sense'? It seems logical to me that you can only configure dependencies for a target that has already been declared, similar to how one can only assign a value to a variable that has been declared before (in C++) fi.

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-06-30**:
You're not wrong, but it depends on what you consider to make sense. Note that order of declaration of targets and dependencies doesn't matter in this way in all build systems, in particular `make`: you can declare targets and dependencies in any order in the `Makefile` and `make` will work it out.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-30**:
True. Perhaps the documentation could be improved. Have you considered submitting an issue to the catkin Github repository? Also, @joq could perhaps add a note to his -- excellent -- catkin tutorials?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-06-30**:
I agree that the docs should not assume everyone knowns CMake well. If you can suggest where information should be added, I will make the update. Here, perhaps? http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html ?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-06-30**:
It's also mentioned here: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html .

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-30**:
@joq: seems it is indeed. Perhaps the wording of the text could be improved a bit by emphasizing the importance of the order of the statements?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-06-30**:
Yes. Just wanted to make sure adding it there would resolve this problem.